# Removing Nodes completely when a specific child element is found

Tags: java, xml

I need to remove the node/nodes completely when a specific child element is found in nodes of XML
For Instance, My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<booklist>
 <book>
     <name>THEORY OF DYNAMICS</name>
     <author>JOHN</author>
     <price>09786</price>
 </book>
 <book>
     <name>ABCD</name>
     <author>STACEY</author>
     <price>765</price>
 </book>
 <book>
     <name>ABCD</name>
     <author>BTYSON</author>
     <price>34974</price>
 </book>
 <book>
     <name>ABCD</name>
     <author>CTYSON</author>
     <price>09534</price>
 </book>
 <book>
     <name>INTRODUCING JAVA</name>
     <author>CHARLES</author>
     <price>1234</price>
 </book>
 <book>
     <name>ABCD</name>
     <author>TYSON</author>
     <price>34534</price>
 </book>
```

So,When i search for book tag ='ABCD'
 my result should be as follows:

OUTPUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<booklist>
 <book>
     <name>THEORY OF DYNAMICS</name>
     <author>JOHN</author>
     <price>09786</price>
 </book>
  <book>
     <name>INTRODUCING JAVA</name>
     <author>CHARLES</author>
     <price>1234</price>
 </book>
```

The code which i tried is as follows:

```
 try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(FILENAME));
        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (int i = 0; i <list.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = (Node) list.item(i);
            // Searching through entire file
            if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("book")) {
                NodeList childList = node.getChildNodes();
                // Looking thhrough all children nodes
                for (int x = 0; x < childList.getLength(); x++) {
                    Node child = (Node) childList.item(x);
                    // To search only "book" children
                    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE &&  
                  child.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("name") && 
          child.getTextContent().toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase("abcd".toUpperCase())) {
                        // Delete node here
                        node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
        parser.parse(FILENAME);                       
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(NEWFILE));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();

        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException saxe) {
        saxe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm unable to delete all the book nodes which has child element as "abcd"  , Instead am able to delete only few alternative book nodes which has child element as "abcd".
Can you suggest me what is the mistake in my code? Why am i unable to delete all the book nodes whose name='abcd'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DOM spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-1590626202), that

> NodeList and NamedNodeMap objects in the DOM are live; that is,
>   changes to the underlying document structure are reflected in all
>   relevant NodeList and NamedNodeMap objects. For example, if a DOM user
>   gets a NodeList object containing the children of an Element, then
>   subsequently adds more children to that element (or removes children,
>   or modifies them), those changes are automatically reflected in the
>   NodeList, without further action on the user's part.

So while you traverse the `NodeList list` and remove nodes from it, these changes are immediately reflected in the `NodeList`. Hence the indexing inside the `NodeList` changes and you never traverse all elements.

One solution to this would be to first collect all nodes, that you want deleted, and afterwards delete them in a separate loop:

```
// ...

Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(FILENAME));
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");

// XXX collection of nodes to delete XXX
List<Node> delete = new ArrayList<Node>();

for (int i = 0; i <list.getLength(); i++) {

    Node node = list.item(i);
    NodeList childList = node.getChildNodes();

    // Looking through all children nodes
    for (int x = 0; x < childList.getLength(); x++) {

        Node child = childList.item(x);

        // To search only "book" children
        if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE &&  
            child.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("name") && 
            child.getTextContent().toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase("abcd".toUpperCase())) {
          // XXX just add to "to be deleted" list XXX
          delete.add( node );
          break;
        }
    }

}

// XXX delete nodes XXX
for( int i=0; i<delete.size(); i++ ) {
  Node node = delete.get( i );
  node.getParentNode().removeChild( node );
}

// ...
```

Alternatively you could just traverse the list backwards, starting at `list.getLength()` going down to `0`.

---

I changed another thing: In your code you traverse all nodes in the document and then manually filter for the `<book>` nodes. I think it would be better to select just the `<book>` nodes in the first place using

```
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");
```

instead of

```
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
```